# Facing issue in getting image from gallery and displaying it in Image-view in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview

> I am working in Fragment in which I need to select an image from
>   gallery and  set it to an imageView. Code is running well, no crashes, no error, but image is not coming into ImageView.

Here is my code :-

```
 public class ProfileOzoneSetting extends Fragment implements OnClickListener   
{

 Boolean setImg ;
NetworkImageView genSetOzoneUserImage;

     private static int RESULT_LOAD = 1;

        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profiesettingozone, container, false);

        genSetOzoneUserImage = (NetworkImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.genSetOzoneUserImage);

       genSetOzoneUserImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent  = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

        }
    });


    APIAccess.fetchData(ProfileOzoneSetting.this, getActivity(), getActivity());
    return rootView;

}
@Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onactivityyyyyfor result ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                genSetOzoneUserImage.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

                setImg = true;
            }
        }
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     AppContoller.getInstance().pref=getActivity().getSharedPreferences(AppContoller.getInstance().PREF_NAME, 0);

        strUserID=AppContoller.getInstance().pref.getString(AppContoller.getInstance().USER_ID, "0");
        APIAccess.fetchData(ProfileOzoneSetting.this, getActivity(), getActivity());
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Please let me know what mistake I am doing here???

Comment: What error you are getting? Post your error log.

Comment: @Vid no errors, no crash. code is running well but image is not coming to the imageview.. :/

Comment: Did you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Chek it out. I have done little bit modification in you code. I should work.

```
public class ProfileOzoneSetting extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

        Boolean setImg ;
        NetworkImageView genSetOzoneUserImage;
        private static int RESULT_LOAD = 1;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profiesettingozone, container, false);
            genSetOzoneUserImage = (NetworkImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.genSetOzoneUserImage);
            genSetOzoneUserImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                    // Show only images
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Image"), RESULT_LOAD);
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

                Uri uri = data.getData();

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                    genSetOzoneUserImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the editing bro, but I am this in my LogCat "07-29 15:09:07.458: W/FragmentActivity(2603): Activity result fragment index out of range: 0x20001
" when I am running the code.

Comment: WC Devraj... It must be some problem with the way you are loading the fragment. Please debug it step by step and check properly where you are stuck.

Comment: I have checked that on stackoverflow and added this  getParentFragment().startActivityForResult() but still having the same issue. selected image is not coming to the ImageView.

Comment: Vid, I tried doing debug, But it is not moving further from onclinkLisetner point and also not giving any king of error other information. can I have your email Id so we can talk over there???

Comment: I am in office, you can come on skype vidyanand.mb